# What is the most efficient way to preload images and stylesheets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to be able to preload images, style sheets and scripts if possible, in order to speed up load time throughout my site, in addition to not having a user see an image load right before them. I am wondering what is the most efficient way to do so?

Does it make sense to place code that is supposed to preload images and stylesheets on every page? In other words, I have duplicated the preloading code.

Does it matter the placement of the preloading code, top of the page, bottom?

Any insight would surely be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // XHR to request a JS and a CSS
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'css/pages.css');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'css/slider.css');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'css/responsive.css');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'css/footer-home.css');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'css/footer-main.css');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'css/contact.css');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'css/3eblog.css');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'css/index.css');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'css/submit.css');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'submit.html');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'css/bootstrap.css');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'js/jquery.cslider.js');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'js/one.js');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'js/two.js');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'js/three.js');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'js/four.js');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'js/five.js');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'js/modernizr.custom.28468.js');
        xhr.send('');
        // preload image
        new Image().src = "images/3elements-issue-1-fall-2013.png";
        new Image().src = "images/3elements-issue-1-fall-2013-current.png";
        new Image().src = "journal-issues/3elements-review-fall-journal-issue-1-2013.swf";
        new Image().src = "journal-issues/3elements-review-fall-journal-issue-1-2013.pdf";
        new Image().src = "journal-issues/3elements-review-fall-journal-issue-1-2013-mobile.pdf";
        new Image().src = "images/mikaela.jpg";
        new Image().src = "images/carol.jpg";
        new Image().src = "images/parker.jpg";
        new Image().src = "images/kids.jpg";
        new Image().src = "images/kids2.jpg";
        new Image().src = "images/kids3.jpg";
        new Image().src = "images/kids4.jpg";
        new Image().src = "images/kids5.jpg";
        new Image().src = "images/kids6.jpg";
        new Image().src = "images/kids7.jpg";
        new Image().src = "images/kids8.jpg";
        new Image().src = "images/kids9.jpg";
        new Image().src = "images/alert.svg";
        new Image().src = "images/3elm.svg";
        new Image().src = "images/drop-down-selector.svg";
        new Image().src = "images/arrow-selector.svg";
        new Image().src = "images/book.svg";
        new Image().src = "images/facebook.svg";
        new Image().src = "images/light-bulb.svg";
        new Image().src = "images/logo.svg";
        new Image().src = "images/logo-2.svg";
        new Image().src = "images/logo-2-denied-page.png";
        new Image().src = "images/mug.svg";
        new Image().src = "images/notepad.svg";
        new Image().src = "images/stumble.svg";
        new Image().src = "images/twitter.svg";
        new Image().src = "images/google-plus.svg";
        new Image().src = "images/favi.ico";
        new Image().src = "fonts/gotham-light.ttf";
        new Image().src = "fonts/gotham-light.otf";
        new Image().src = "fonts/gotham-medium.ttf";
        new Image().src = "fonts/gotham-medium.otf";
        new Image().src = "fonts/gotham-book.ttf";
        new Image().src = "fonts/gotham-book.otf";
        new Image().src = "fonts/gotham-bold.ttf";
        new Image().src = "fonts/gotham-bold.ttf";
        new Image().src = "fonts/pts.ttf";
        new Image().src = "fonts/pts.otf";
        new Image().src = "fonts/pts.woff";
    }, 1000);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, you should have a look at arrays and loops: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"`.. in order to speed up load time throughout my site, in addition to not having a user see an image load right before them`"

Those requirements contradict. A user sees an image loading before him, because the page is displayed before the image is loaded.

Pre-loading doesn't speed up loading. If you pre-load all images before initial page view, the initial page view becomes slower. Pre-loading is especially useful for images you want to display later, like a (different) background image on hover. Although sprites are usually the better option. Pre-loading css seems useless to me.

If you want to speed up the initial page load, use a CDN. You can even create multiple domains or subdomains to the same server. This allows browsers to download more files at once. Most browsers have a restriction that allows them to only download 2 files simultaneously from the same server. By setting up multiple domains or subdomains, you can trick browsers into thinking that there are multiple servers. Of course, your server must be powerful enough and have enough bandwidth to support the extra requests, otherwise it won't help.

All that aside, the code you have now needs to be available on every page if you want it to work. You can never now which page is going to be the entry page. If you want to pre-load the exact same files, you can put this code in a separate script file, so it is cached, saving loading time on each page that is visited consequtively.

If you like, you can set a cookie when all images are pre-loaded, so you do it only once per session.

The code itself is better placed at the bottom of the page. That allows the page to be displayed, while this script itself is still running, although it won't matter very much, since it will be quite fast (it only sets a timer).

Comment: I've made some changes afterwards. Maybe the downvoter wasn't happy with my initial answer which was too generic, not answering the question directly. Anyway, my answer is updated and the downvoter seems to have changed his mind. Hurrah for the voting system! ;)

Comment: How would I set a cookie when the images are preloaded?

Answer (score 0):

I see no point in doing this at all. Browsers file onload event after everything is loaded up so the solution is to do something like

```
window.onload = function() {document.body.style.display = "block"};
```

Having the inline style for body:

```
<body style="display:none"> ... </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the images anyway. With "preload" I guess you mean you want to fade them only in when they are loaded.

You do this with layering a `div` above the images and fade it out on image load.

```
$('img').on('load', function() {
    $('yourImageHidingDiv').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best is to using Image holder with small GIF as background , once the images have been loaded , just remove the background .

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#loading").hide()
}
```

and the #loading background image should be something like this : 
http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading1.gif